# unintuitive selection in a pandas dataframe using a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I came across a weird situation using boolean numpy arrays as a mask for selecting parts of a pandas dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.ones((3,3))
data[-1, -1] = 10

data = pd.DataFrame(data)


data[data==1]
data.where(data == 1, np.nan)
data.where(np.array(data == 1), np.nan)
```

All commands will result in the expected output:

```
   0  1   2
0  1  1   1
1  1  1   1
2  1  1 NaN

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

However this one does not:

```
data[np.array(data==1)]

   0  1   2
0  1  1   1
0  1  1   1
0  1  1   1
1  1  1   1
1  1  1   1
1  1  1   1
2  1  1  10
2  1  1  10

[8 rows x 3 columns]
```

What's the reasoning behind this?
I tested this on pandas 0.13.1 and 0.16.0.

Comment: This is a bug I see this when stepping through `> c:\winpython-64bit-3.4.3.1\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py(2437)apply()
-> for b in self.blocks:
(Pdb) self.blocks
(FloatBlock: slice(0, 3, 1), 3 x 3, dtype: float64,)` this is an invalid slice which results in incorrect values being set: `> c:\winpython-64bit-3.4.3.1\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py(922)eval()
-> values = self.values
(Pdb) self.values
array([[  1.,   1.,   1.],
       [  1.,   1.,   1.],
       [  1.,   1.,  10.]])`

Comment: According to API, are boolean masks allowed to be numpy arrays?  It seems that problems could arise with a mask being a numpy array rather than a series or dataframe since you lack index and column names/labels.  Although `data.where(np.array(data == 1), np.nan)` does seem to work here, it's not obvious to me that you should count on that.  Also, a very general comment:  it is not real unusual to get strange results like this when mixing arrays and dataframes.  If you got a result like this using an array mask on an array or a dataframe mask on a dataframe that would be much more of a concern.